# How to apply 3 values for 1 row to 3 rows with each value?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a number of ROWS that have 1 to 6 values. For example:

```
Param1: A|B|C|D
Param2: B|Y
Param3: A
```

I need to transform it like this:

```
Param1: A
Param1: B
Param1: C
Param1: D
Param2: B
Param2: Y
Param3: A
```

Well, I guess a pivot-unpivot might work, but there are a lot of conditions and fields I need to get. Also, I have a View that divides all values and counts them. In the top example it will return dataset like this:

```
A 2
B 2
C 1
D 1
Y 1
```

Here is my own example, which is working alright on a few records and works very badly with more than 100000 rows.

Initial story is about this. I have some objects(obj), each has its params(prm), which have its values (val). So, as you see, each object is like a tree, which I need to expand.
Here is a simulation:

```
DECLARE @x TABLE
    (
      prm INT ,
      iin VARCHAR(20) ,
      oout VARCHAR(20)
    ) 
INSERT  INTO @x
VALUES  ( 1, 'A/B/C', 'A' )
INSERT  INTO @x
VALUES  ( 1, 'A/B/C', 'B' )
INSERT  INTO @x
VALUES  ( 1, 'A/B/C', 'C' )
INSERT  INTO @x
VALUES  ( 3, 'D', 'D' )
INSERT  INTO @x
VALUES  ( 2, 'R/G', 'R' )
INSERT  INTO @x
VALUES  ( 2, 'R/G', 'G' )

DECLARE @y TABLE
    (
      obj INT ,
      prm INT ,
      val VARCHAR(20)
    ) 
INSERT  INTO @y
VALUES  ( 10, 1, 'A/B/C' )
INSERT  INTO @y
VALUES  ( 10, 2, 'R/G' )
INSERT  INTO @y
VALUES  ( 10, 3, 'D' )
INSERT  INTO @y
VALUES  ( 20, 2, 'R/G' )
INSERT  INTO @y
VALUES  ( 20, 3, 'D' )

DECLARE @z TABLE
    (
      id INT ,
      obj INT ,
      prm INT ,
      val VARCHAR(20)
    ) 
INSERT  INTO @z
VALUES  ( 1, 10, 1, NULL ) 
INSERT  INTO @z
VALUES  ( 2, 10, 1, NULL ) 
INSERT  INTO @z
VALUES  ( 3, 10, 1, NULL ) 
INSERT  INTO @z
VALUES  ( 4, 10, 2, NULL ) 
INSERT  INTO @z
VALUES  ( 5, 10, 2, NULL ) 
INSERT  INTO @z
VALUES  ( 6, 10, 3, NULL ) 
INSERT  INTO @z
VALUES  ( 7, 20, 2, NULL ) 
INSERT  INTO @z
VALUES  ( 8, 20, 2, NULL ) 
INSERT  INTO @z
VALUES  ( 9, 20, 3, NULL )
```

And decision:

```
;
WITH    a AS ( SELECT   ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY prm ORDER BY prm ) n ,
                    *
           FROM     @x
         ),
    b AS ( SELECT   ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY obj, prm ORDER BY obj, prm ) n ,
                    *
           FROM     @z
         )
UPDATE  b
SET     b.val = a.oout
FROM    b
        INNER JOIN @y y ON y.obj = b.obj
                           AND y.prm = b.prm
        INNER JOIN a ON a.n = b.n
                        AND a.prm = b.prm
                        AND y.val = a.iin
SELECT  *
FROM    @z
```

**@y** table - is a table with arguments like the first example, where Param1,Param2 is 1,2 ets on column *prm*, concerning some object in *obj*
**@z** table - is simulation with *val* set to null, which represents, what params should be filled with values
**@x** table - is a simulation of dividing of values, that should be applied to **@y** table, replacing the null values of the **@z** table with actual ranked values.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Well I'll not give you a full solution, but if I need split data like this, I'd try to use `sqlxml` (you have to try it on large number of rows to check if performance ok for you):

```
declare @x table (prm int,iin varchar(20))

insert into @x values(1, 'A/B/C')
insert into @x values(3, 'D')
insert into @x values(2, 'R/G')

select
    x.prm, x.iin, T.C.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)') as oout
from @x as x
    outer apply (
        select cast('<d>' + replace(x.iin, '/', '</d><d>') + '</d>' as xml) as Data
    ) as D
    outer apply D.Data.nodes('d') as T(C)
```

see [**<kbd>sql fiddle demo</kbd>**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/19743) to try it.

Comment: +1, I do not know if this is a optimal solution when the data set is large but it works, and is a good solution for split a field by a character into different rows. (in this case "/"). Many thanks.

Comment: In my expirience, if you need to do it often, it's better to write clr regex split function, but for small data xml working fine.

Comment: Well, first of all thanks! But there is one problem. I never know which kind of separation will be. U see - a provider gives me a list of 10 billion rows (that means objects with parameters and values list). And from my side there are predefined parameters and values. And manually I link a parameter from Provider's list to parameter from my DB. The same about values. At last - I get data to rank from my DB tables, rather than string with values itself. That's why sqlxml can't fit pretty well. And its impossibile to work with data as a strings only. But please, don't hezitate to write again!tnx