# SQL Server 2008 things coming out in wrong order sometimes

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a strange problem that only occurs occasionally. I have run it 10000 times and got 2 errors, 12 errors and no errors at different times.

Here is my test script that tries it 10000 times and outputs the ones in error

```
declare @i int
set @i = 10000

declare @v varchar(200)

while @i > 0
begin
    SELECT top 1 @v = val
    FROM f_split_string('a,b,c,d,e,f',',')
   if @v != 'a'
       print @v
   set @i = @i - 1
end
```

And here is the `f_split_string` function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[f_split_string] (@s nvarchar(max), @delim nvarchar(10))
-- returns a table from a delimited string
-- Parameters:
--    @s                The delimited string
--    @delim            The delimiter characters
-- Example:
--    SELECT val FROM f_split_string('a b c',' ')
RETURNS @t TABLE (id int, val nvarchar(max))
AS
BEGIN
      DECLARE @c int, @v nvarchar(max)
      SET @c = 1
      SET @v = dbo.f_element(@s, @delim, @c)
      WHILE @v IS NOT NULL
      BEGIN
            INSERT INTO @t (id,val) VALUES (@c,@v)
            SET @c = @c + 1
            SET @v = dbo.f_element(@s, @delim, @c)
      END

      RETURN
END
```

And here is the `f_element` function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[f_element](@Input varchar(max), @Delimiter varchar(10), @ElementNumber int)
-- returns an element from a delimited string
-- Example:
--   SELECT dbo.f_element('abc|def|ghij', '|', 2)
--     will return the 2nd element - def
RETURNS varchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
      DECLARE @Pointer INT, @Count INT, @Last INT, @retVal varchar(max)
      SET @Pointer = 1
      SET @Count = 1
      SET @Last = 1

      WHILE (@Count < @ElementNumber)
      BEGIN
            SET @Pointer = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@Input,@Pointer)
            IF @Pointer = 0
                  BREAK

            SET @Pointer = @Pointer + DATALENGTH(@Delimiter)
            SET @Count = @Count + 1
      END

      IF @Pointer = 0 OR @ElementNumber < 1
            SET @retVal = null;
      ELSE IF SUBSTRING(@Input,@Pointer,DATALENGTH(@Delimiter)) = @Delimiter
            SET @retVal = '';
      ELSE
      BEGIN
            SET @Last = @Pointer

            SET @Pointer = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@Input,@Last+1)

            IF @Pointer = 0
                  SET @retVal = SUBSTRING(@Input, @Last, 9999)
            ELSE
                  SET @retVal = SUBSTRING(@Input, @Last, @Pointer - @Last)
      END

      RETURN @retVal
END
```

This is being tested on SQL Server 2008 (not R2)

Firstly, can anybody else get errors with my test script, secondly, why is this happening?

I have run the f_element function 200000 times with no problems, so suspect the f_split_string function, but it might be the f_element function when being called from f_split_string

I have run it on a single user SQL Server 2008 R2 with no problems, the 2008 has multiple users

Can anybody help me

The error is the wrong part of the delimited string.  It should be the a, but sometimes it is other parts.  Its as if the rows are being inserted into the temporary table in the wrong order.  I added the id column to the temporary table so I could sort the output, but it made no difference.

Comment: And..what is the error?

Comment: The error is the wrong part of the delimited string.  It should be the a, but sometimes it is other parts.  Its as if the rows are being inserted into the temporary table in the wrong order.  I added the id column to the temporary table so I could sort the output, but it made no difference.

Comment: Do you call the function `f_split_string` with longer strings? because maybe you could try with this solution, please see this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18516485/1563878).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL gives you no guarantee of ordering if you don't put an explicit ORDER BY statement.

Even an example as simple as yours -- where you'd expect that the internals should work out like you want them to -- shows that this is not the case.

Solution: add an ORDER BY if the order is important. I understand you have nothing to sort on, so maybe modify your split function so that it spits out two columns: value and index; you can then sort on the index.

Comment: Can you post code for this attempt? Using ORDER BY and not getting this order out of the query would be a very serious SQL Server bug.

Comment: Just found out that the DBA didn't put it live like he said he did - very annoying and a wasted hour - thank you anyway

Answer (score 0):

In addition to my previous answer, maybe I can point out another option.

If using CLR procedures in your DB is an option for you, this is the kind of job where CLR code is more performant than T-SQL. Additionnally, because the CLR function is seen as an opaque enumerator by SQL Server, you *may* rely on `SELECT * FROM dbo.clr_func()` to be in the same order as the `clr_func` enumerator, although I guess you shouldn't try to push your luck and make the query any more complex than that.

Because I don't see the point of such a simple SELECT, you will probably have to turn to ORDER BY anyway for more serious business.

If you are interested in this option you can have a look at the *Using the CLR* section of this article:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17802/Use-Table-Valued-Functions-as-Arrays-in-SQL-Server